# How to pass input as argument of a function?

Tags: python, django, request

So I need my function to use user's input but when I try to configure it that way, it says the id is missing (the id is the number the person writes in the input).
This is not working the way it's supposed to (the numbers are not passed to the get_person function):

```
cuit_r = request.POST.get('cuit')
```

This is the error:

```
Error:  Missing element idPersona (getPersona.idPersona)
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import requests
from django.views import View
from .forms import MonotributoForm
from app.ws_sr_padron import get_persona

class ConstanciaInscripcion(View):

   def get(self, request):
      return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
   
   def post(self,request):

       if request:
           
           form = MonotributoForm(request.POST)
           
           cuit_r = request.POST.get('cuit')
           response=get_persona(cuit_r)

           if response is True:
               print(response["persona"]['nombre'])
               print(response['persona']['apellido'])
           else:
               print("cuit ingresado no existe")

           if form.is_valid():
               cuit = form.cleaned_data.get('cuit')
               email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
               cuit.save()
               email.save()
               return HttpResponseRedirect('app/constancia-inscripcion.html')

           
       else:
            pass 
       
       return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
```

This is my form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Monotributo

class MonotributoForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
       model = Monotributo
       fields = ['cuit','email']
```

Answer (score 1):

What i do is the next..

```
def adding_data(request):
    f = request.POST['first_name']
```

Instead of use `request.POST.get()` i write `request.POST()`